# Check if the directory exists and if it does not exist show a message box stating that it does not exist

Tags: c#

in windows forms 2017 Express, i want to check if the directory the file exists and if it does not exist show a messagebox stating that the file it does not exist

Code:

```cs
string str = @"Y:\Tester\MAIN.exe";
Process process = new Process();
process.StartInfo.FileName = str;
process.Start();
```

And what i want is, if a directory does not exist, then Put a

```cs
Messagebox.Show("Directory Not Found);
```

Just like this: If this directory: "Y:\Tester\MAIN.exe" dont exist put that messagebox.show.

I want to check if the directory exists, and if exists, check if the file exists too; Or just if the directory exists or not and return a messagebox.

Comment: Just check File.Exists(str)

Comment: You can use `Directory.Exists` to check if a directory exists, but be warned, it will check if a **directory** exists. Since I suspect `MAIN.exe` is a **file**, it will return false even if the file exists. To check if a file exists, use `File.Exists`. Or did you mean by "this directory" to check if `Y:\Tester` doesn't exist? If so you first need to split the path from the filename, use the `Path` class to do that. `Path.GetDirectoryName` will do that for you.

Comment: ? Why are you taking about "directory" while the path shows a specific file??

Answer (score 0):

```
/* Use: 

  if (!OSTools.ExeFileHandler.Perform(@"Y:\Tester\MAIN.exe")
       MessageBox.Show("Action failed");  
*/

namespace OSTools
{
    using System.Diagnostics;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Windows.Forms;

    public static class ExeFileHandler
    {
        public static bool Perform(string strExe)
        {
            if (!Directory.Exists(Path.GetDirectoryName(strExe)))
                MessageBox.Show("Directory Not Found");
            else
            if (File.Exists(strExe))
            {
                Process process = new Process();
                process.StartInfo.FileName = strExe;
                process.Start();
                return true;
            }
            else MessageBox.Show($"File {strExe} Not Found");
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```